# How to reference calling element in custom plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a simple jQuery plugin and I'm trying to reference the calling element in my `shrink()` function. I know that if I don't pass the element then `this` will refer to `window` but is there a way to refer to the element that called the jQuery plugin? If not, then how would I pass `this` in the callback of `$(window).on('resize', shrink);`?

```
$(function ($) {
    $.fn.shrinkIt = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            className: "shortened",
            maxWidth: 800
        }, options);

        var shrink = function (elem) {
            var $this = $(elem);
            var viewerWidth = $('.header').width();
            if (viewerWidth > 800) {
                $this.removeClass(settings.className);
            } else {
                $this.addClass(settings.className);
            }
            $this.css('visibility', 'visible');
        };

        return this.each(function () {
            shrink(this);
            $(window).on('resize', shrink); // how to get 'this' to shrink() function??
        });
    };

    $('.lessonDocumentType').shrinkIt();
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `var $this = $(this);` inside the first function (`$.fn.shrinkIt`).

Any inner function within that function can now refer to `$this`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your approach. Instead of define a listener for each element, attach one time the listener and manage all elements:

```
$(function ($) {
    $.fn.shrinkIt = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            className: "shortened",
            maxWidth: 800
        }, options);

        var $els = $(this);
        $(window).on('resize', shrink);
        function shrink() {
            $els.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var viewerWidth = $('.header').width();
                if (viewerWidth > 800) {
                    $this.removeClass(settings.className);
                } else {
                    $this.addClass(settings.className);
                }
                $this.css('visibility', 'visible');
            });
        };
        return this;

    };

    $('.lessonDocumentType').shrinkIt();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @bflemi3 mmh no why do you think that? You have all elements in `$els` and is always accessible inside the function

Comment: You can't do this `$('lessonDocumentType').shrinkIt().css('color','red');` now because you're not returning the element(s)

Comment: @bflemi3 Simply I missed `return this`, sorry :-)